# Override link color inside a tooltip?

Tags: material-ui

I have a material ui `tooltip` component with a `link` component inside of it. I need to change the link colour. Is this possible?

I have tried the following, but it does not work:

Theme

```
MuiTooltip: {
    tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: "#222",
        color: "#fff"
    }
    MuiLink: {
        root: {
            color: isLight(primaryColour) ? primaryColour : "#fff"
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference the `tooltip` rule name with `.MuiLink-root` as descendant

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTooltip: {
      tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: "#222",
        color: "#fff",
        "& .MuiLink-root": {
          color: isLight(primaryColour) ? primaryColour : "#fff"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[image: Edit crazy-rgb-j4pq5]

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed.